# Cerrar PreparedStatement si voy a retornarlo en un método?

Tags: java

Si tengo un método que va a retornar un `PreparedStatement` pero tengo una cláusula `try/catch/finally` donde cierro dicho `PreparedStatement` que sucederá ?

```
try {
        // preparamos la consulta   
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(consultaPaginada);
        ps.setLong(1, max_row_to_fetch);
        ps.setLong(2, min_row_to_fetch);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //TODO: handle exception
    }finally{
        if(ps != null){
            ps.close();
        }
    }            

    return ps;
```

El valor de `ps` estará a `null`? o esta correcto esta implementación?

Comment: Dado que hay una clara intención de cerrar el PS, supongo que a posteriori lo que te interesa son los datos del PS. Entonces, ¿no es mejor guardar el resultado del PS en una variable, cerrar el PS y retornar la variable con el resultado? No tiene sentido mantener el PS abierto, retornándolo, a no ser que te interese seguir operando con ese PS, como por ejemplo pasarle otros parámetros para obtener más datos o algo así.

Comment: Cierto, podría hacer eso, no se me había ocurrido. Gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: Conviene tener claro que **un PS no son los datos**, es un objeto que te permite preparar una consulta, ejecutarla y eventualmente obtener los datos en un `ResultSet`, pero ¡un `ResultSet` tampoco son los datos!, es como un puntero hacia los datos el cual debes leer para obtener, finalmente, los datos. Una de las ventajas de los PS (aparte de la seguridad) es que, una vez preparada la consulta, puedes **reutilizarla**, por ejemplo, para pasarle otros datos distintos y obtener otros resultados, agilizando el rendimiento, el SGBD ya conoce el camino al haber preparado por 1ª vez la consulta.

Comment: Y como guardo el PS en una variable para después retornarla? Porque entiendo que la variable tambien tiene que ser de tipo PS y tambien habría que cerrarlo no?

Comment: Si realmente te interesa retornar el PS, tendrías que declarar que el tipo de retorno de ese método es `PreparedStatement`, algo así:  `public PreparedStatement mPreparedStatement ( ... parametros ... ) { //código .... y hacer un return del objeto PS  que hayas creado}` pero dado que el PS seguirá vivo en el contexto desde el cual lo llamarás, para seguir usándolo, sea para leer los resultados, sea para lanzar otra consulta, no puedes pensar en cerrarlo aquí, sino donde lo hayas llamado, cuando ya no lo necesites.

Comment: De acuerdo, haré eso. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a mi problema ha sido cerrar el `PS` donde llamo al método  `mPreparedStatement ( ... parametros ... )`

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;

try {
    ps = mPreparedStatement ( ... parametros ... );
}catch(SQLExcepcion e){
    throw(e);
}finally{
    try{
        if(ps!=null)ps.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```